# Unable to add pre-calculated standard errors to ggplot using errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data below, how to add the error bar in ggplot, when the se are codified in separate rows?

Mrdoc_g1_se corresponds to mrdoc_g1.

```r
a %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("doc"),
               names_to="key", values_to="value")   %>%
  mutate(tmp = stringr::str_split_fixed(key, "_", 2),
         group = tmp[,1],
         key = tmp[,2],
         se = ifelse(str_detect(key,"_se"), value, NA_real_)) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(key, "_se")) %>% 
  # filter(value != 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(key,-value), y=value, fill= group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  # add standard error bars
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = value - se, ymax = value + se), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
                width = 0.25) + # add error bars
  facet_grid(reliability~group, scale = "free_x") + # rcc scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Parameters", y = "Diff estimated - parameter value")
```

[image]

```r
structure(list(reliability = c("Reliable", "Unreliable"), mrdoc_g1 = c(0.0477292229736724, 
0.0268894607076981), mrdoc_b1 = c(-0.000250050925494134, -0.000250059430178553
), mrdoc_b2 = c(0.0227228767058806, 0.0336386689509775), mrdoc_ra = c(-0.0597290435589332, 
-0.0412515615946694), mrdoc_rc = c(-0.0491019783134211, -0.0278071729801267
), mrdoc_ey = c(-0.0101491345296546, 0.0429186214404244), mrdoc_ex = c(-0.000447326510881639, 
0.00662058921023644), mrdoc_ax = c(-0.000158366514505874, -0.000158409692032231
), mrdoc_ay = c(0.0467823071312944, 0.0486627367470403), mrdoc_cx = c(-0.000157933413358391, 
-0.000158099783524738), mrdoc_cy = c(-0.00399105727108018, -0.00222088997772851
), mrdoc_g1_se = c(0.0277752611239866, 0.0292386755856376), mrdoc_b1_se = c(0.0179515374408753, 
0.0180408344823349), mrdoc_b2_se = c(0.0223338921215588, 0.0233936230713459
), mrdoc_ra_se = c(0.545882467442342, 0.575136713969931), mrdoc_rc_se = c(0.481789355222727, 
0.507456215975629), mrdoc_ey_se = c(0.0188006779700206, 0.0198916835785712
), mrdoc_ex_se = c(0.0183716584442592, 0.0185042610457241), mrdoc_ax_se = c(0.134992145193822, 
0.136850346085672), mrdoc_ay_se = c(0.117996256541202, 0.129988013151702
), mrdoc_cx_se = c(0.107690784022973, 0.109148727414679), mrdoc_cy_se = c(0.109534751459347, 
0.120374519011968)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Because your `se` column contains only NAs.

Comment: Yep, corrected now. Also, simplified a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you messed up your dataset when reshapeing and wrangling and you ended up with an `se` column containing only NAs. To fix your issue I simplified by first renaming your columnbs consistently to use the `names_pattern` argument of `pivot_longer` so that no further wrangling is necessary:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>%
  rename_with(
    ~ paste(.x, "value", sep = "_"),
    !ends_with("se") & !reliability
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -reliability,
    names_to = c("group", "key", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(key, -value), y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = value - se, ymax = value + se),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    width = 0.25
  ) +
  facet_grid(reliability ~ group, scale = "free_x") + # rcc scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Parameters", y = "Diff estimated - parameter value")
```

[image]